# Send JSON data from in socket.io from android

Tags: java, android, json, node.js, sockets

I have used https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client for socket programming in android. Now i am receiving JSON response and now i want to send JSON data to this node.js server from my android application please help me out. here is my code

```
buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // socket = null;
            try {
                SocketIO socket = new SocketIO(
                        "http://104.131.225.38:8001/");

                socket.connect(new IOCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(JSONObject arg0,
                            IOAcknowledge arg1) {
                        try {
                            Log.i("Server saidwsssss:",
                                    "sssss" + arg0.toString(2));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(String arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {
                        Log.i("Server said:", "" + arg0);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(SocketIOException arg0) {
                        Log.i("OnError", "" + arg0);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDisconnect() {
                        Log.i("Connection Terminated",
                                "Connection Terminated");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnect() {
                        Log.i("Connection Established",
                                "Connection Established");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void on(String arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1,
                            Object... arg2) {
                        Log.i("Server Trigger Event:", "" + arg0 + ""
                                + arg1);
                        if (arg0.equals("nbUsers")) {
                            Log.i("DONE", "DONE" + arg0.toString());
                        }
                        Object[] arguments = arg2;
                        Log.i("Args", "" + arguments[0].toString());

                    }
                });
                socket.send("hello server");
                socket.emit("event", "argument1", "argument2", 13.37);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a Gson object that permit to transform your object into a JSON String, and apply a conversion to a JSONObject like this :

```
Entity en = new Entity();
Gson gson = new Gson();
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(en));
    socket.emit("entity", obj);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is how I do. To use Gson, you should add a Gradle dependency :

```
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+'
```

Comment: Can you please just tell me there are many responses that i am getting. Now i want all the responses from node.js and from that all responses i want to send data to one response .

Comment: I dont really understand. You want to get information from node, many time ( you already did the code) and you want to send data to node as answer (you already did it with socket.emit and socket.send)

Comment: i want to get the response in my android application from socket.io how to do that? my event name is **findAllUsersResponse**. how to achieve this?

Comment: ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(args[0].toString()); // getting the first argument
JSONObject object = jsonObject.getJSONObject("entity"); // getting a node inside the previous json
Entity entity = mapper.readValue(json, Entity.class); in your "on" method