# Gson toJson returning string of JSON instead of JSON Object

Tags: android, json, kotlin

The Class that I'm using with `toJson`

```
class LoadUserDTO: Serializable {
    @SerializedName("userGuid")
    var userGuid: String? = null

    @SerializedName("userToken")
    var userToken: String? = null

    constructor(userGuid: String, userToken: String) {
        this.userGuid = userGuid
        this.userToken = userToken
    }
}
```

And the rest of the use:

```
val payload = LoadUserDTO(userGuid = user.guid!!, userToken = user.token!!)

val jsonPayload = Gson().toJson(payload)

this.socketService.socket.emit(EndpointsEnum.AppLoadUser, jsonPayload)
```

The jsonPayload should be a JSON Object. Instead, the entire thing is a String of what should be a JSON Object:

```
"{"userGuid":"...","userToken":"..."}"
```

When this is received by the server, it's not receiving a JSON Object as the Web UI or Swift App sends, but is instead just a String, not converted to a JSON Object.

Comment: can u log what payload contains?

Comment: What do you mean by a JSON object? what is your expected output compared to whats currently happening? How do you know it is sending a string?

Comment: @DevWithZachary I can set a breakpoint on the API endpoint. The data is a string, when it should be an object. When I do the same thing via the Web App its an object, also when I do it from the iOS App, it's an object. In this case it's sending across as a string.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var jsonString = """{"id":1,"description":"Test"}""";
var testModel = gson.fromJson(jsonString, TestModel::class.java)
```

Comment: I'm not looking to create a Java Object. I want an actual JSON Object sent over the wire instead of a string of the JSON Object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement instead using `Gson` you may use  `String.format` to achieve this by one line of code -

```
   // val payload = LoadUserDTO(userGuid = user.guid!!, userToken = user.token!!)
   // val jsonPayload = Gson().toJson(payload)
     val jsonPayload = String.format("\"{\"userGuid\": \"%s\"," + "\"userToken\": \"%s\"" + "}\"",user.guid,user.token)
   // Log.d("ZI",jsonPayload)
```

Output- example

```
"{"userGuid": "1234","userToken": "token000"}"
```

You may remove `space` after `:` while formatting string .

```
       val jsonPayload = String.format("\"{\"userGuid\":\"%s\"," + "\"userToken\":\"%s\"" + "}\"",user.guid,user.token)
```

Output-

```
"{"userGuid":"1234","userToken":"token000"}"
```

Comment: I have a lot of DTOs to setup as Objects. I definitely don't want to have to deal with string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why yet, but this SO Question gave me the answer for it to work:

[Send JSON data from in socket.io from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932613/send-json-data-from-in-socket-io-from-android)

```
val jsonPayload = Gson().toJson(payload)

val jsonObj = JSONObject(jsonPayload)

this.socketService.socket.emit(EndpointsEnum.AppLoadUser, jsonObj)
```

After making the `jsonObj` the server now has a properly formed JSON Object that it can work with.